# Avoid showing old data with react + redux. Always wait for fetch complete

Tags: reactjs, redux

From this guide I found here:

https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-redux/

I have a pretty standar reducer that handle data, loading and error:

```
import {
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN,
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE
} from './productActions';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
      };

    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload.products
      };

    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
        items: []
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And then the component that call the action and draw based on those states:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProducts } from "/productActions";

class ProductList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }

  render() {
    const { error, loading, products } = this.props;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>;
    }

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
      <ul>
        {products.map(product =>
          <li key={product.id}>{product.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.products.items,
  loading: state.products.loading,
  error: state.products.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductList);
```

This works fine the very first time:

**products** is empty. So the first render will show the empty list. The second time(after the fetch is completed) products will have items.

Now, the problem is what happens if I get outside then component and then re-enter(for example, using react-router).

The very first time It will draw with the cached information in the redux-store. Then after the fetch I will redraw the new list.

Is there any way to avoid this every time?

i have thought a couple of "solutions" but I'm not soure if they will work/are good practices:

1. setting in the component state a value "fetchId" (example, generating a random UUID) and use it in the **fetchProducts** action. That value would be saved in the redux store and the compare the redux fetchId with the component. If they are the same, DRAW! If they are differente(the fetchId comes from a different call) I will not draw anything.
2. Cleaning up redux store calling an action in the **componentWillUmount**

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Store the product I'd in Redux and only render the product if it matches the one the user has selected. If it doesn't match, fetch the requested product.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. What if the user has some list of products? There are way better solutions that just cutting corners like these